# Two name servers?

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

I was told by my domain registrar that they require two name servers per domain name. I want to host my own DNS (to try it out, this isn't an important website) on my own server. I only really need one name server.

Two questions: Is this two name server minimum a common requirement and will it work if I set ns1.website.com and ns2.website.com to the same IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some have two, some have four (which is the maximum). Pinging my hosts NS addresses shows that each one is hosted on a different IP.

The reason for the requirement is failover - if the first NS fails the second is used and so on down the list.

So, you can set both the nameservers to the same address but bear in mind you won't have any backup if your primary nameserver fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! This is just a website for my troop and I can easily change it back to my registrar's DNS if needed, but I'm eager to try it out.

Comment: Go for it, but you might want to keep one of your registrars NS in third place just for safety.